# Jquery Autocomplete ajax request only if item from previous ajax request data is not matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery Autocomplete.
It's making an AJAX request on every keypress which I don't want. If data from a previous AJAX request matches a search it should not make any more AJAX requests.

```
<script>
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/TestDDl/Index',
                // data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.user, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: data.name,
                            val: data.val
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        keypress: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Not Selected');
            if (!ui.item) {
                alert('Not Selected');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here if I am typing the name of a user which is already in previous AJAX request data, it should not make an AJAX request on next the keypress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable, assing user input to it, then update it in your success function. And just before making next call, check if your variable matches the next data.

Something like this:

```
<script>
    var recent = '';
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            if (recent == request.term) {
                return;
            }
            recent = request.term;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/TestDDl/Index',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.user, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: data.name,
                            val: data.val
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        keypress: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Not Selected');
            if (!ui.item) {
                alert('Not Selected');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script>
    window.xyz = []; //For saving history
    $('#tags').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            if(xyz[request]){
                response(xyz[request]); // Return previously saved data
            }else(
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/TestDDl/Index',
                    // data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var res = $.map(data.user, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: data.name,
                                val: data.val
                            }
                        });
                        xyz[request]=res; //set data to reuse later
                        response(res)
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        keypress: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Not Selected');
            if (!ui.item) {
                alert('Not Selected');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your next ajax reques should be in the Success function of the first ajax request.Buid the logic there.If you find the match don't call the second ajax request else call the second ajax request and all should be in the success function of the first ajax request.

Comment: how ?? because on every keypress event ajax request is made from source?? can you suggest me in ma code

Comment: please try it how you understand.